# Socket Creation causing force close

Tags: java, android

whenever I open a socket in android, the program immediately force closes. Here's the code:

```
package com.bensherman.acc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.43.253", 4452);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here's my manifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bensherman.acc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.bensherman.acc.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the log:

```
    05-20 19:26:59.539: E/Trace(26558): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-20 19:26:59.649: D/AndroidRuntime(26558): Shutting down VM
05-20 19:26:59.649: W/dalvikvm(26558): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b545300)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bensherman.acc/com.bensherman.acc.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2190)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4978)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at com.bensherman.acc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-20 19:26:59.669: E/AndroidRuntime(26558):    ... 11 more
```

Does anyone have an idea what's the problem? It isn't a problem if I say Socket socket = new Socket(). I have a server running on my computer, although both the laptop and development device are connected via a phone running wifi tether.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: you just need to move the socket creation to a new thread for it and manage the information sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Well try searching a little bit more about networking on Android, first you are not allowed to use networking on UIThread on latest versions of android. Second did you set permissions correcly? It is better for you now to do a little bit more research than to go with some lousy solution.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.